# Google Sheets API v4 dot Net Deleting a row

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am building an interface to tie in with Google Sheets.  The way it works is all of the records from a spreadsheet are pulled into a grid view on my interface.  There is then a button on this interface offering options such as Edit, Delete, etc.

I am having trouble with my delete method.  The way it works is all of my records are pulled in to the method which then uses a for loop to go through the results and compare the ID field from the result to the ID that is passed into the method. When there is a match, that is the one to be deleted.  All of this works and everything goes off smoothly, but for some reason, the record is not deleted from my google sheet. Below is my code for the dot NET wrapper of Google Sheets API v4.  If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated. I've been staring at documentation and piecing together parts of other languages for a couple of hours now and my brain isn't coming up with anything new, lol.

```
if (ID.ToString() == WHVACRMembers[i][0].ToString()) // IF INCOMING ID MATCHES ID OF CURRENT ROW BEING LOOPED OVER
{
    //DELETE THIS ROW
    Request RequestBody = new Request() { 
        DeleteDimension = new DeleteDimensionRequest() { 
            Range = new DimensionRange() { 
                SheetId = 0, 
                Dimension = "ROWS", 
                StartIndex = Convert.ToInt32(i), 
                EndIndex = Convert.ToInt32(i) 
            } 
        } 
    };

    List<Request> RequestContainer = new List<Request>();
    RequestContainer.Add(RequestBody);

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest DeleteRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    DeleteRequest.Requests = RequestContainer;

    service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(DeleteRequest, SpreadsheetID);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. Instead of:

```
service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(DeleteRequest, SpreadsheetID);
```

I needed:

```
SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest Deletion = new SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest(service, DeleteRequest, SpreadsheetID);
Deletion.Execute();
```

As soon as I figured that out, everything went through without a hitch. Was just a matter of me not being focused on the right thing while looking through the documentation and object explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same number for StartIndex and EndIndex was not deleting the row for me, I had to add 1 to EndIndex:

```
            StartIndex = Convert.ToInt32(i), 
            EndIndex = Convert.ToInt32(i + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Please note code is in Java so please convert, this is just to show you my approach.*

I'm not sure if my approach is best one or not but it is serving the purpose, so I'll explain what I did.

1. Keep one extra column(say ROWNUM) in the sheet where you are saving
   data.
2. Write same string "=ROW()" in this column each time when
   you're posting data, it will generate the row id for that row
3. Then utilize the following method, hope it helps!

   ```
   public void deleteRows (String range, String textToBeDeleted) {//textToBeDeleted is cell value which will be find in the column and that row will be deleted

   try {
       Sheets sheetsService = createSheetsService();
       ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
               .get(spreadsheetId, range)
               .execute(); //Getting all the data of the sheet

       List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
       List<List<Object>> allData = response.getValues();
       List<Integer> rowsToBeDeleted = new ArrayList<>();

       for (List<Object> row : allData) {
           if (row.get(0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(textToBeDeleted)) { //0 is the column value based on which I'll be deleting the row
               rowsToBeDeleted.add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(23).toString())); //23 is the RowNumber column in my case
           }
       }

       BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
       for (int i = rowsToBeDeleted.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //Reverse loop while deleting so that wrong index doesn't get deleted
           Request request = new Request();
           request.setDeleteDimension(new DeleteDimensionRequest()
                   .setRange(new DimensionRange()
                           .setSheetId(sheetid)
                           .setDimension("ROWS")
                           .setStartIndex(rowsToBeDeleted.get(i) - 1)
                           .setEndIndex(rowsToBeDeleted.get(i))
                   )
           );
           requests.add(request);
       }
       requestBody.setRequests(requests);

       Sheets.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate deleteRequest =
               sheetsService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, requestBody);

       BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse deleteResponse = deleteRequest.execute();

       System.out.println(deleteResponse);

   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
   }}
   ```